# Group is abelian iff Cayley table is symmetric along its diagonal axis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> The [Cayley table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) tells us whether a group is abelian. Because the group operation of an abelian group is commutative, a group is abelian if and only if its Cayley table is symmetric along its diagonal axis.

Sorry, but why is this true?

Comment: Otherwise, what can the table look like? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number the elements of the group, and then think of the Cayley table as a matrix: in the $ij$-th entry, we have $g_ig_j$.

If the Cayley table is symmetric, then the $ij$-th entry is equal to the $ji$-th entry, so $g_ig_j=g_jg_i$, and so the group is abelian.

Conversely, if the group is abelian, then $g_ig_j=g_jg_i$ for every $g_i,g_j$ in our group. Therefore, the $ij$-th entry is equal to the $ji$-th entry in the Cayley table, so the table is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

The [Caley table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) describes the group action ("multiplication") between elements, so if the action is commutative (abelian), then table is symmetric (along the diagonal for $a \ne b$), since $a \circ b = b \circ a$

if seen as a matrix of group actions with indices $i, j$ for $i$-th element and $j$-th element, then $T_{ij} = T_{ji}$ (symmetric matrix)